# How can I create a json file using python which will contain one key and under that multiple key value pairs using a for loop

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, for-loop, nested

I want my Json file to look like this-
The Name values I am taking from another Json file.

```
{"Name1":{
    "Age": 30,
    "Gender": "Male",
},
"Name2":{
    "Age": 25,
    "Gender": "Female",
}}
```

My current script is like this:

**Here I am fetching the name value from another Json file.**

```
for k in data['person']:
    Name = k['name']
    dictionary =  {Name:{
        "Age": 25,
        "Gender": 'Female'
    }}
json_file = json.dumps(dictionary,indent = 4)
```

But I am getting output like -

```
{
    "Name1": {
        "Age": 35,
        "Gender": "Male"
    }
}{
    "Name2": {
        "Age": 30,
        "Gender": "Female"
    }
}
```

And so on like this.

Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is an indent mistake in your code and that you are actually dumping `dictionary` inside the loop. Hence the bad formatting of your output (also `Age` should be 25 and `Gender` Female for both elements since they are hardcoded in your loop).

You should first create an empty dictionary that you will update with `dictionary` at each step:

```
out_dict = {}
for k in data['person']:
    Name = k['name']
    dictionary =  {Name:{
        "Age": 25,
        "Gender": 'Female'
    }}
    out_dict.update(dictionary)

json_file = json.dumps(out_dict,indent = 4)
```

Output:

```
{
    "Name1": {
        "Age": 25,
        "Gender": "Female"
    },
    "Name2": {
        "Age": 25,
        "Gender": "Female"
    }
}
```

BTW `json_file` is a string and not a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these options to create a nested dictionary

```
import random 
import json
# Option 1
dummy_data = {'person': { f"Name{num}":{"Age": random.randint(9, 50) ,"Gender": random.choice(['Female', 'Male']) } for num in range(3)} } 
json_file = json.dumps(dummy_data, indent = 4)
json_file

# Option 2 
data_ditc = {
  "Name0": {
    "Age": 10,
    "Gender": "Male"
  },
  "Name1": {
    "Age": 29,
    "Gender": "Male"
  },
  "Name2": {
    "Age": 15,
    "Gender": "Male"
  }
}

data_person = {'person': {} } # = {'person': dict()}
for k, v in data_ditc.items():
  data_person['person'].update({k:v})

json_file2 = json.dumps(data_person, indent = 4)

# Option 3 

data_person2 = dict()
for item in data_ditc.items():
  data_person2.setdefault('person', {}).update(dict([item]))

json_file3 = json.dumps(data_person2, indent = 4)
```